# 500 error when trying to open any order from Admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

> In admin panel homepage, when I click on any order from the "Last 5
>   orders" section I get a 500 error.
>
> I have tried reading var/log/system.log, and below is the log that was
>   created when I encounter that 500 error.

```
  Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Customer/Model/Attribute.php' for 
  inclusion (include_path='/home/xxx/public_html/app/code/local:/home/xxx/public_html/app/code/community:/home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core:/home/xxx/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') 
  in /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Is there anything I could do to resolve or identify the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Is the customer who placed the order is present in the system? Are those customer been removed from the system.

Comment: The customer is present in the system and has NOT been removed. it basically happen to any order that I click on.

Comment: Hmm is there the file present on that mentioned location? I mean to say if you have accidently removed the core files? Check that first.

Comment: The "Mage/Customer/Model/Attribute.php" was missing, I copied and everything is fixed! please put this as answer instead of comment. Do you know what might cause the "Core" related files to be deleted? I have never touched anything in the "Core" folder.

Comment: Hi I have updated the same to the answer. Please accept and vote up if it helps, it will help other to get to the solution too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the file is missing

> Mage/Customer/Model/Attribute.php

If yes copy it from the core magento setup and paste it in the location to get the issue fixed.

Comment: The file was missing, but I wondering what could lead to the deletion of that file?

Comment: Maybe done via an ftp connection - ask your host for ftp transfer logs. Maybe via a merge if your site is under version control.